# Deleted Linux Partition , Stuck on grub rescue , Cannot load any OS

Tags: grub2, windows-10, fedora

I installed Fedora on my computer by freeing up 20GB from the E drive in Windows 10 . But i realised that i didn't like the interface much , so i went back to windows disk management and noticed that 20GB of space was still free and so without deleting anything on it , i put all that space back into my E: drive on windows 10 . Now , after i restarted my computer , i got stuck on grub rescue which says Error : Unknown Filesystem . After some research on google , i found out that it was due to me deleting that linux partition which also deleted the grub bootloader which handled the booting of Windows and Linux . I found the following solutions to help me :

1)Repair the MBR bootloader which the Windows originally used by going into the command prompt using the Windows 10 bootable usb and putting in the command

```
BootRec.exe /fixmbr
```

The bootable windows 10 usb ends up getting stuck in the restart loop i.e. on the windows logo loading screen with the white dots moving in a circle .

2)Use a Ubuntu or any other Linux distro live usb and run gpart to format my HDD

I have tried to run/install Fedora , Ubuntu and Mint but they always get stuck in the process . Ubuntu always reports many errors like "Out of memory" "Kill process or sacrifice child" in a list whenever i try to "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu"

3)Use the following commands in the grub rescue terminal :

```
set boot=(hd0,msdos7)<br>
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub<br>
insmod normal<br>
normal<br>
```

This did get me to the grub menu which showed me the OS available on my HDD (Ubuntu and Windows 10) but whenever i clicked on Windows 10 , it got stuck in the restart loop i.e. at the windows logo loading screen and whenever i clicked on Ubuntu , it got stuck on a blank screen .

Please help .

Comment: I had problems booting and it was due to wasted RAM cards. I spent moths battling and when i checked the RAM it didn't stop reporting errors in the tests.

You can read a Wikihow article that says the Bootloader loads the system to RAM.

Please try to boot the USB in another computer after testing the RAM, for that you will need to enter the BIOS. How to do that is given by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . Before , i realized that since i can't boot any OS like Ubuntu , Fedora , Windows , etc. using their boot images , i should try to format my HDD completely . But i couldn't format my HDD using any of the boot image programs like Active KillDisk , DBAN , Gpart etc. Then i came across Ultimate Boot CD and booted from that . Then i chose BOOTMGR ( Multi-Boot Manager ) program on it and selected my HDD on it . Then i selected 'Zap Disk' which 'Erases MBR and tracks 0 & 1" . Now , i simply reinstalled Windows using my Windows installation USB . 
Note : This method deletes all the data on your HDD .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Windows bootloader got hosed.  I know Windows used to have a "Rescue" mode that would effectively reinstall Windows files over themselves.

Your #2 error does sound like RAM... the Ubuntu disk should have a memtest option.  You can download and burn a memtest ISO if you don't have it and want it faster than downloading a whole 'nother live CD.

Comment: Before it starts killing processes , it always says "Write Protect is off "  "No Caching mode page found" "Assuming drive cache : write through" "Attached SCSI removable disk" "random : nonblocking pool is initialized "